# Upload Files with Space in Name on Google Cloud SDK Shell

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud Storage, but have managed to find every answer to my questions online, but now I'm trying to upload files using the Google Cloud SDK and it works great for files with no spaces "this_file_001.txt" but if I try to upload a file with spaces "this file 001.txt" the system won't recognize the command. The command I'm using that works is

> gsutil -m cp -r this_file_001.txt gs://this_file_001.txt

Now the same command with spaces doesn't work

> gsutil -m cp -r this file 001.txt gs://this file 001.txt

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Putting the argument into quotes should help.  I just tried the commands below using [Google Cloud Shell terminal](https://console.cloud.google.com?cloudshell=true) and it worked fine:

`$ gsutil mb gs://my-test-bucket-55
Creating gs://my-test-bucket-55/...
$ echo "hello world" > "test file.txt"
$ gsutil cp "test file.txt" "gs://my-test-bucket-55/test file.txt"
Copying file://test file.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
Uploading   gs://my-test-bucket-55/test file.txt:                12 B/12 B
$ gsutil cat "gs://my-test-bucket-55/test file.txt"
hello world`

That said, I'd avoid file names with spaces if I could.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, will try it and let you know. I'm using spaces because that's how files were created from the beginning, but will avoid it in the future.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey's suggestion about quoting is good. If you're on Linux or a Mac, you can likely also escape with a backslash (). On Windows, you should be able to use a caret (^).

Linux example:

```
$> gsutil cp test\ file.txt gs://bucket
```

Windows example:

```
c:\> gsutil cp test^ file.txt gs://bucket
```

Quotes work for both platforms, I think.