# Cannot open file with spaces in file name but uploads fins in google cloud storage version 1.103.1

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am uploading a file to gcs which has spaces in its name. The upload is fine. However when I try to read the file it fails.

Does anyone know of a solution for this? Or if google has fixed in a particular version?

I am using 1.103.1. Google cloud storage.

Update: 
API being used:
Blob get(String var1, String var2, Storage.BlobGetOption... var3);

The file is an user input. So I have to enforce that on the user if needed. I want to see if it can handle filename with spaces.

Thanks
Avinash

Comment: What is the command that you are using? What operating system? Are you enclosing the filename with quotes?

Comment: How are you trying to read the files? Please share an example. Also are you using the filename with quotes as John Hanley pointed? I would recommend to you to not use spaces but underscore (_).

Comment: I am using the following API
Blob get(String var1, String var2, Storage.BlobGetOption... var3);
The file is an user input. So I have to enforce that on the user if needed. I want to see if it can handle filename with spaces.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use "-" or "_" instead of spaces in order to check if this is working? Also you will avoid any further issues that may occur.

Comment: So the problem is many files with spaces in their names have already been uploaded. I need a way to access them. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277416/upload-files-with-space-in-name-on-google-cloud-sdk-shell). It explains how to upload files with spaces including an example. I assume it is the same for download please try it. Also I will recommend to you to not use spaces in order to be easy programmatically to do any changes.